# What should be the (practical) number of consumer/producers on a single connection in ActiveMQ setup?

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms

I want to know how many consumers/producers should be on a single connection?
At what number should I distribute my consumers over separate connections?

I have multiple DMLC's with concurrent consumers but they are using single connection.
I have around 100 consumers using same connection. Should I distribute them?
I haven't faced any problems but just asking if is this a good thing ?

What is costlier for ActiveMQ to handle - two connections with 50 consumers or 100 consumers on single connection?

I have asked this on activemq forum also but nobody has replied - [link](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/No-of-consumers-per-connection-in-ActiveMQ-td4696635.html).

Thanks,
Abhi

Answer (score 1):

I think 100 consumers using single connection is better than multiple connections for same number of consumers as connections are costlier than consumers. But it is difficult to say how many max concurrent consumers you can have per connection.

Also please make sure that you have very low prefetch size set for these concurrent consumers otherwise total prefetch buffer size increases.

Answer (score 0):

There is likely no hard and fast rule; it will depend on so many things.

I suggest you try it both ways and use whichever is best for you. But bear in mind, the results might be different on your test Vs. production environment.

> I haven't faced any problems...

This is often called "premature optimization".